# 401 Authorization Required on ajax requests but retry succedees

Tags: php, apache, ntlm, squid

We use apache with NTLM on our server:

```
NTLMAuth on
AuthType NTLM
AuthName "Auth"
NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp"
NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
require valid-user
```

And this gives as an error when we use ajax, most of our ajax requests fail on the first try with message "401 Authorization Required" but on automatic retry they succeed, why is there a difference between both requests?

Our application works but this error is annoying, uses resources and slows down application.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what you're actually seeing is not some sort of "automatic retry" behavior, but is the [challenge-response authentication of NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication).  By its nature, you will have to add an extra round-trip to the first request on a connection.  The authentication **should** look like this:

1. Client requests a resource that is protected by NTLM authentication.
2. The server will reply with a 401 unauthorized and indicate the mechanisms that it supports (in this example, NTLM).
3. The client requests the resource with the initial NTLM authentication message (the "type 1" message) which contains the user's domain and username as well as the capabilities of the client.
4. The server responds with a 401 unauthorized and the NTLM challenge (the "type 2" message).
5. The client computes a response to the server's challenge, and then requests the resource with the final NTLM authentication message (the "type 3" message).
6. The server responds with the appopriate code - if the authentication did not succeed, this will be a 401, if the authentication did succeed, this will be success, not found, etc.

So yes, you will use some additional resources to do NTLM authentication (over using Basic authentication, anyway.)  Note, however, that NTLM authenticates a **connection** not a **request**.  Thus, subsequent requests over the same kept-alive HTTP connection do not need to reauthenticate.  This lessens the burden of the challenge-response nature.

Finally, note that most web browsers that support NTLM or SPNEGO are prepared for this, and will use expect/continue.  Thus, they will not send POST data (for example) in the initial connection until they're authenticated and get an HTTP continue from the server which should also lessen the burdern.